# Set-content: stream was not readable

Tags: powershell, streaming

I have a simple script that reads a file and adds new information to it. The script gets 2 parameters: `srv` and `key`. If `srv` is already exists, add `key` to the end of the line. If not, add to the end of the file.

The logic works fine. The problem is that I am getting `get-content: stream was not readable` in most cases (but not always) when `srv` already exists.

If I am printing `$arrHosts` just before `set-content`, it is the right array. So I assume it is a temporary problem with streaming `$hostsFile`.

I'm hoping for a fix in Powershell and not .NET.

Script:

```
[string]$srv = $args[0]
[string]$key = $args[1]
$hostsFile = '..\file_destination..\..'
[array]$arrHosts = Get-Content $hostsFile

if ($arrHosts -ne $null)
{
    for ($i=0; $i -le $arrHosts.Length; $i++)
    {
        if ($arrHosts[$i] -match "$srv\s")
        {
            $arrHosts[$i] += " $key"
            break
        }
        elseif ($i -eq $arrHosts.Length)
        {   
            $arrHosts += $srv+" "+$key
            break
        }
    }
    $arrHosts | Set-Content -Path $hostsFile
}
else
{
    Add-Content -path $hostsFile -value "`n$srv $key"
}
```

Comment: Couldn't find any useful solution for this question. Found similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370389/add-content-produces-stream-not-readable) but the solution wasn't right

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are approaching this problem correctly.  I would do it the same way.  Can you share some examples of the error message?  Which part of the script is throwing the error?

I would comment on your above question but I do not have the required reputation.